# UI-Bootstrap multiple collapsibles

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

The usual collapsible example is this...

```
<div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
<hr>
<div collapse="isCollapsed">
    <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div> 
</div>
```

and this...

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', function ($scope) { 
  $scope.isCollapsed = false; 
});
```

But what if you have more than one collapsible and want to collapse only one? This example will open or close all of them.

Comment: What you describe sounds like an 'accordion' interface component, see http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ near the top.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is given in the comment. Yet writing it as an answer.

Use [angular ui accordion](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) instead of multiple collapsible panels.